# Bluetooth filesystem sync?

Tags: filesystems, sync, file-management, bluetooth

Does such software exist?

What I'd like to do is keep a set of files updated between two machines using bluetooth so that I may edit them on both computers, and changes get automatically synchronized whenever they are within range of each other. Functionally a little like what Dropbox does via the network. But, without requiring the internet. A lightweight local bi-directional link.

This would be extremely convenient especially if it can also be secure, and it has the potential to be far more secure than something like Dropbox.

Comment: Try Dropbox LAN sync over a Bluetooth PAN?

Comment: That would work typically. Turns out my work computer can't connect to dropbox though. Let me edit my question.

Comment: Ah, I see. Still, why the strict "no IP" requirement? *No Internet* would make more sense.